# Custom Xcode 5 Project Templates only half working

Tags: c++, xcode, templates, xcode5

Ok so I got the custom file templates working when I add a new C++ file to the project,
but when I create a new project, the comment section on the template is still at it's default.

I feel like I have tried everything, and need some help.

Im using the "Command Line Tool" template for my C++ projects.

When I made my custom file template I just edited

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/C and C++/C++ Class.xctemplate/___FILEBASENAME___ .cpp`

When I get to the "Command Line Tool" project folder I'm not sure exactly what I am supposed to do to get it to work. I edited the TemplateInfo.plist to add `#include <iomanip>` and that worked fine but I see no where to edit the comments. The location of that file is at

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project        Templates/Mac/Application/Command Line Tool.xctemplate/TemplateInfo.plist`

I've been stuck on this for a few hours now so any help would be a life saver!
Thanks for the help!