# Xcode 5 - change ___COPYRIGHT___

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I've read how to change the entire templates used in Xcode, or how to change the `Organization Name` that is used in the `___COPYRIGHT___` variable of the templates, but how do I change the value of the `___COPYRIGHT___`?  Is there one template I can change?  I do not want to change every template that uses `___COPYRIGHT___`.

We need to change from

```
//  Copyright (c) 2013 me. All rights reserved.
```

to

```
//  Copyright (c) 2013 me and my affiliates.
```

I do not want to change all the templates as suggested by [Change copyright / top-comment / "header" on ALL new files in Xcode 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311839/xcode5-change-copyright-top-comment-header-on-all-new-files).

Comment: There's some nice Unix console programs that can be combined to do this?

Comment: Go into View --> Show Project Navigator. Click on the Project Name then go into View --> Utilities --> Show File Inspector. If you scroll down there is a place for Organization.

Comment: I don't want to change the Organization name... I want to change the entire row of text that is replaced in the templates by ___COPYRIGHT___

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it os only one specific line:  `// Copyright (c) 2013 me. All rights reserved.` and you want to change only this you can do it simply by `cmd+alt+F` (Find & Replace) in `XCode`.

Correspondingly you can do this in `AppCode` by using `cmd+shift+R` (Find & Replace). Might be a bit different depending on your key mapping.

In both solution you can decide about each case all do it for all occurrences.

If it is not working properly you can write a script (once I did script doing more complex thing with headers in python and it worked nicely).

I'm suggesting this solution as you said you do not want to change any template.

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: I'm willing to change one template if __COPYRIGHT__ also gets set in a template.  I do not want to change all of the templates.

Comment: I want it to be right for any developer when they create a new file; looking for a fool proof plan.  I'm more likely to try to get our policy changed so that we can use the build in format for copyright and just get our organization name correct instead of changing the entire message.  I don't want to rely on some step to be performed after the file is created.  I don't want to run the script as part of the build, because we've had problems in Xcode 5 and running scripts during the build.

Comment: what would you said about python script launching from terminal?

Comment: Looking for a solution that will not be missed during new development.  @logixologist comment above is the closest answer I can find on the web, which is almost what I need.

Comment: where is that comment?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45834/discussion-between-jason-hocker-and-viperking)