# Issue when create new file in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I'm using Maverick, Xcode4, Xcode5. I always have got an issue when I create any new file in Xcode. It generate some lines information about **my name** but it generate **issues**. So I must to comment that line to prevent. This is very stupid.
It's look like:

```
//
//  FinanceSettingController.m
//  MyApp
//
//  Created by 
Dat Nguyen on 2/24/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 axonactive. All rights reserved.
//
```

Can anyone help me do setting Xcode or OS preference to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By chance does your name in the Contacts app have a leading linefeed character?

Comment: There is a good answer to this question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311839/xcode5-change-copyright-top-comment-header-on-all-new-files

Comment: Search before put your question guys

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20311839/change-copyright-top-comment-header-on-all-new-files-in-xcode-5