# Make changes to Xcode project templates

Tags: xcode, templates, xcode5

I have read a few posts about creating/editing Xcode project templates, but they don't seem to work with Xcode 5.

The directory in which I have to make changes is, /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/Project Templates/Mac/Application/Command Line Tool.xctemplate

However, I can't figure out a place where I can make changes and include the header files and other statements that I wish to add.

[image: Here is the screenshot of the folder]

I have even tried editing C++ class in the File Template. However, the problem is that the custom class comes into play only when I add a new c++ class to the project. No changes are visible are in main.cpp

Comment: You shouldn't be messing with the Xcode.app bundle; you probably have to put them under `~/Library/Developer/Xcode` or somesuch.

Comment: There isn't a folder inside Library/Developer. There's just an Acknowledgements.rtf

Comment: So create one.  The path is `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates` (and note that `~/Library` is hidden from Finder so you need to unhide it using `chflags nohidden ~/Library` from the shell).

Comment: Okay, but the problem is that I don't know which file to edit to add the required header files.
I need to to make changes to that file and then add an edited version of the template to this folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have the project file here which sets up the base files needed and not extra files.

When you add a new file you us a template under `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates`

To do this for a C++ class copy `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/C and C++/C++ Class.xctemplate` to `~//Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/<myGroup>/C++ File.xctemplate` (replacing  by the group name you want. Then edit the files in this target directory.