# Override Xcode's default templates

Tags: xcode, templates, xcode6

I want to modify Xcode's default templates but only for a given user in my Mac. I tried following the steps in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20335959/1838805), but instead of overriding the default templates it created new ones. You can see the result in the following image.

[image]

Is there any way I can tell Xcode to use only my custom templates without modifying the original files?

Comment: I answered the question you linked to. In my answer I said to duplicate Apple's templates so following my steps is going to create duplicates. I do not know of any way to restrict file templates to a specific user. I recommend creating a custom group for your templates and place the templates in that group. With a custom group you can avoid the confusion shown in your screenshot. Apple's templates will be in the Source group, and your templates will be in your custom group.

Comment: I thought of doing exactly what you said but then I realized that when you create a new project, Xcode uses its own templates and not the ones I created.

Comment: File templates are for adding files to existing projects. If you want different files in a new project, you need to create custom project templates. There's a discussion on that in the comments in my answer that you linked to in your question.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize I also needed to create project templates